# Kernel of a multiplication map of global sections of line bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^3$, $C$ be a smooth projectively normal curve in $X$ and $\mathcal{L}$ be a line bundle on $X$ of the form $\mathcal{O}_X(-D)$ for some (reduced) curve $D$. Let $k$ be a positive integer such that $\mathcal{L} \otimes_X \mathcal{O}_C$ is $k$-regular (in the sense of Castelnuovo-Mumford regularity). Does there exist a positive integer $n$ such that the dimension of the kernel of the natural morphism from $H^0(\mathcal{L} \otimes_X \mathcal{O}_C (k)) \otimes H^0(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(n))$ to $H^0(\mathcal{L}\otimes_X \mathcal{O}_C(k+n))$ is strictly less than $h^0(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(n))$?

Comment: I think so. Take a general genus 4 curve, embedded canonically in $\mathbb{P}^3$ as a $(2,3)$ complete intersection. Take $\mathcal{L}=\mathcal{O}$, $k=1$ and $n=2$. Then $h^0(\mathcal{O}(3))=20$, the multiplication map  seems to have Kernel of dimension 4.

Comment: I have the feeling that you have something different in mind or did not reveal all the conditions. If $\mathcal L$ is arbitrary, this is clearly trivially true. In other words, for any $k\in \mathbb N$ there exist infinitely many $\mathcal L$ such that the desired condition holds for any $n\in \mathbb N$, namely take $\mathcal L=\mathscr O_{\mathbb P^3}(-k-m)|_C$ for any $m\in\mathbb N_{+}$. Then the left term of the tensor product is zero and hence so is the kernel.Requiring that this group is not zero is no help, with a little work you can figure out that it would work for $m=0$ as well....

Comment: @Kovacs: I have edited the question.

Comment: @user43198: the above examples still work.

Comment: @Kovacs: I am sorry. I am a bit confused. The above example is a line bundle of a specific form (pull-back of  the dual of an ample line bundle). Does it also hold for any line bundles as in the question?

Comment: Aha! I didn't notice that you changed "is it possible" to "is it true". Now it's completely unclear what you are asking. Try to edit the question with some qualifiers: Do you mean whether for all possible $D$ and all possible $k,n$ this is true or that some of these could be anything and some chosen. In other words, clarify which part of the input should be all and which should be there exists. Can you write your question in the form: Let $D$ be an arbitrary bluh, does there exist a bluh-bluh, so that for every bluh-bluh-bluh, bluh-bluh-bluh-bluh holds. (etc.)

Comment: @Kovacs: I have edited the question. Is it clearer now?

Comment: What does it mean for $\mathcal L \otimes_X \mathcal O_C$ to be $k$-regular? Do you mean the integer $n$ should be strictly greater than $0$?

Comment: @Sawin: Regularity in the sense that the higher cohoomology vanish after twisting by  $\mathcal{O}_X(m)$ for $m \ge k$ (same as the  Castelnuovo-Mumford regularity). Yes. I want $n>0$. I will edit this into the question.